# Sharing a JavaVM* across threads in Android NDK

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to call Java class methods from a cpp file that receives call backs from another executable.

To achieve this, I have retrieved a JavaVM pointer using the **android::AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM()** method in the .cpp file that directly receives JNI method calls. I am sharing this JavaVM pointer via the constructor to the eventual .cpp file where I call required Java methods as follows:

```
/* All the required objects(JNIEnv*,jclass,jmethodID,etc) are appropriately declared. */
**JNIEnv* env;
jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
clazz = env->FindClass("com/skype/ref/NativeCodeCaller");
readFromAudioRecord = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "readFromAudioRecord", "([B)I");
writeToAudioTrack = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "writeToAudioTrack", "([B)I");**
```

However, I get a  **SIGSEGV** fault running this code.

According to the JNI documentation this seems to be the appropriate way to obtain JNIEnv in arbitary contexts: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html#26206

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Regards,
Neeraj

Comment: What is android::AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM) ? That is not NDK public API function. You are using something undocumented. To get JavaVM* in NDK you must implment JNI_OnLoad global function that is automatically called when your shared library gets loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/#NWD1sCYeT-J - this document gives a very good intro to JNI_OnLoad, where android::AndroidRuntime::registerNativeMethods() is used. Are you sure android::AndroidRuntime is non documented?

Comment: Yes, it undocumented feature in normal user NDK code. Read the JNI documentation (from Sun) and check the docs/STABLE-APIS.html file in your NDK folder for other legal & documented API.

Comment: And that document is about Android programming before NDK came out. Read the first section "Important Notice".

Comment: Thanks again for pointing that out. I removed the call to android::AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM() and used JNI_onLoad instead to propogate the JavaVM* pointer. However,still get the same SIGSEGV fault. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global references will NOT prevent a segmentation fault in a new thread if you try to use a JNIEnv or JavaVM reference without attaching the thread to the VM. You were doing it properly the first time around, Mārtiņš Možeiko is mistaken in implying that there was something wrong with what you were doing.

Don't remove it, just learn how to use it. That guy doesn't know what he's talking about, if it's in jni.h you can be pretty sure it's not going anywhere. The reason it's not documented is probably because it's ridiculously self explanatory. You don't need to create GlobalReference objects or anything either, just do something like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <linux/threads.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "[NDK]"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

static pthread_mutex_t thread_mutex;
static pthread_t thread;
static JNIEnv* jniENV;

void *threadLoop()
{
    int exiting;
    JavaVM* jvm;
    int gotVM = (*jniENV)->GetJavaVM(jniENV,&jvm);
    LOGI("Got JVM: %s", (gotVM ? "false" : "true") );
    jclass javaClass;
    jmethodID javaMethodId;
    int attached = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, &jniENV,NULL);
    if(attached>0)
    {
        LOGE("Failed to attach thread to JavaVM");
        exiting = 1;
    }
    else{
        javaClass= (*jniENV)->FindClass(jniENV, "com/justinbuser/nativecore/NativeThread");
        javaMethodId= (*jniENV)->GetStaticMethodID(jniENV, javaClass, "javaMethodName", "()V");
    }
    while(!exiting)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_mutex);
        (*jniENV)->CallStaticVoidMethod(jniENV, javaClass, javaMethodId);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_mutex);
    }
    LOGE("Thread Loop Exiting");
    void* retval;
    pthread_exit(retval);
    return retval;
}

void start_thread(){
    if(thread < 1)
        {
            if(pthread_mutex_init(&thread_mutex, NULL) != 0)
            {
                LOGE( "Error initing mutex" );
            }
            if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, threadLoop, NULL) == 0)
            {
                LOGI( "Started thread#: %d", thread);
                if(pthread_detach(thread)!=0)
                {
                    LOGE( "Error detaching thread" );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LOGE( "Error starting thread" );
            }
        }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_justinbuser_nativecore_NativeMethods_startThread(JNIEnv * env, jobject this){
    jniENV = env;
    start_thread();
}
```

Comment: Where did I say that using something from jni.h is wrong or not allowed?

Comment: "That is not NDK public API function. You are using something undocumented. To get JavaVM* in NDK you must implment JNI_OnLoad global function that is automatically called when your shared library gets loaded." Sorry to say it but that entire statement is just plain incorrect.

Comment: And that is true - `android::AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM` is not a public function or method in jni.h. I never said that using functions or methods from jni.h (such as global JNI_OnLoad, or JavaVM, or JNIEnv) is not allowed. But you implied that I said something about him not using it properly with functions from jni.h. How can he be doing it properly with **android::AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM** function from android internals that is not in jni.h?

Comment: Yes it is a public function in jni.h, on top of which I included an example of exactly how it's used in the source above if you had bothered to look through it. What he was doing was correct and you told him he was wrong, that's what I was reacting to.

Comment: Are you serious? In which line of jni.h there is android namespace (or  class) that has AndroidRuntime namespace (or class) that has getJavaVM function?

Comment: Here is jni.h file from NDK r8d platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include\jni.h: http://pastebin.com/04RgHUYN Please show me where is `android` and `AndroidRuntime` namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. The segmentation fault was because I could not retrieve a jclass object from the JNIEnv object retrieved from the shared jvm pointer.

I propogated a Global reference jclass object alongwith the jvm and the problem was solved.

Thanks for your help Mārtiņš Možeiko!..

Regards,
Neeraj