# How to get a reference to the JVM from a native android executable?

Tags: android-ndk

I've successfully built and run a native executable using the NDK. It is a regular C++ application with no java entry point (e.g., no xyz_activity, just int main()). Now I need to access some methods from the android runtime through JNI, but i can't seem to get a hold of the JavaVM*. jni_getcreatedjavavms isn't exported by the NDK, and neither is AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM(). So that leaves me with JNI_OnLoad which is only called for shared libraries. I already tried splitting the project up into an executable and a .so file containing JNI_OnLoad, but I guess that only works when doing an explicit System.loadLibrary call. However the project doesn't contain any java code at all. How do I obtain a reference to the JVM?

Answer (score -1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13772600/14612474) you can access JVM using jni environment (JNIEnv):

```
JavaVM* jvm;
int gotVM = (*jniENV).GetJavaVM(&jvm);
```